# Trouble compiling Wolf's cpuminer-multi on Mac OS X

Tags: cpu-mining, macos, compile

I’m new to Monero. I’ve got three Macs setup as nodes mining through monero-cli-wallet and a windows machine which I have configured for pool mining. On the advice of many threads I selected a smaller pool (https://moneroworld.com/#) and followed the instructions there to get my Windows PC connected to the pool with CPU and GPU miners. All seems to be going well in about a week I’ll have enough XMR to actually get a payout ;-)

What I would like to do is contribute my three Macs to the pool  (all running Mac OS Sierra 10.12.2). I looked at all of the other pools help pages to see if they had easy Mac setup but it appears the only open-source way is to compile Wolf’s cpuminer-multi from GitHub. I have not been able to compile it successfully. I managed to get the dependencies installed without issue (jansson from GitHub - yes I know it is included in the cpuminer-multi tree but I wanted to see if I could at least install something from source off of GitHub; and Curl through Home-Brew ).

**The instructions I am following are:**

git clone https://github.com/wolf9466/cpuminer-multi

cd cpuminer-multi

./autogen.sh

1. I got *'aclocal'* error so installed automaker via Home-Brew which seems to fix it
2. Then got error *‘configure.ac:133: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_ERROR.If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow. See the Autoconf documentation.’* Fixed with 'brew install pkgconfig'.

CFLAGS="-march=native" ./configure #seems to run fine with no errors reported that I can see

make #error: *‘make: No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.’*

Is there a some other syntax for the make command I need?

On another note, does Wolf’s AMD GPU miner work on Mac OS? Once I figure out my cpu miner-multi issues I’d like to tackle that if it runs ok as both my iMacs have AMD graphics cards?

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Regards,

Greg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had the same trouble as you. Thankfully there is an OSX fork by correcthorse that's worked for me:

https://github.com/correcthorse/cpuminer-multi

It has the build instructions for OSX in the readme:

> - install Xcode from app store
> - install Xcode command line tools `xcode-select --install`
> - accept Xcode license `sudo xcodebuild -license`
> - install Homebrew `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
> - `brew install autoconf automake pkg-config`
> - continue with Basic *nix instructions

Basic *nix build instructions:

> - `./autogen.sh` # only needed if building from git repo
> - Optimal GCC flags are built in - you only need to use -march=native if you want it
> - `CFLAGS="-march=native" ./configurec` (Use -march=native if building for a single machine)
> - `make`

Comment: This github link is invalid

Comment: I just compiled on Mac OS with this new version: https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak